# How to apply the Telugu font to the spinner?

Tags: android, web-services, android-fonts

In my application I have use JSON web services.Through the web services I get Telugu font. How to add this Telugu font to my spinner?

```
LayoutInflater lv = getLayoutInfalter();
View v = lv.inflate(R.layout.spineerfont,false);
TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.sp);
Typeface faceGautami = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "gautami.ttf");
tv.setTypeface(faceGautami);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the font through your own custom `SpinnerAdapter`, in `getView()` and `getDropDownView()`.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View row = inflater.inflate(yourRowlayout, parent,false);
TextView make = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sp);
Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/gautami.ttf");
v.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
v.setText(itemList.get(position));
return row;
}


public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View row = inflater.inflate(yourRowlayout, parent,false);
TextView make = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.sp);
Typeface myTypeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
            "fonts/gautami.ttf");
v.setTypeface(myTypeFace);
v.setText(itemList.get(position));
return row;
}
```

Comment: already i have use ArrayAdapter.In ArrayAdapter i have pass the this layout R.loayout.spineerfont

Comment: Edited my answer. check